# Trouble creating the SPS_HOME environment variable

Tags: python, bash, macos, terminal, astronomy

I am trying to install the python-FSPS package [as shown](https://dfm.io/python-fsps/current/installation/), which first requires me to install [FSPS](https://github.com/cconroy20/fsps) itself. After having version conflict issues between conda/brew/etc I decided to wipe everything and start over, installing python 3.7 again.

I moved everything including all my installed packages to `~/python3.7/site-packages/` where I cloned FSPS. Next, I went to edit my `.bashrc` file located at `~/.bashrc` where I added `setenv SPS_HOME ~/python3.7/site-packages/fsps` as instructed. Note that the `.bashrc` file was empty to start. I even edited `.bash_profile` and added `SPS_HOME= ~/python3.7/site-packages/fsps` and ran `export SPS_HOME` before restarting the shell.

I can make everything just fine in `src` but when I try `echo $SPS_HOME` I get nothing in return. I used to be able to create it just fine when anaconda was installed but maybe I accidentally got rid of something important? What would cause this to not create the variable? I cant install python-fsps without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove space in `SPS_HOME= ~/python3.7/site-packages/fsps`.